# Divergence integral evaluation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let W be the region bounded by planes $$x=0, y=0, y=3, x+2z=6$$ Evaluate the surface integral   using Gauss Divergence theorem where F= $$ 2xy \hat i + yz^2 \hat j + xz \hat k$$

I am able to set bounds correctly- 
x: 0 to 6, y: 0 to 3, z: 0 to $$\frac{6-x}{2}$$

The divergence of F is $$2y + z^2 + x$$

hence, by Gauss divergence theorem,

$$\int_0^{6}\int_0^{\frac{6-x}{2}}\int_0^{3} (2y+z^{2}+x)dydzdx$$

But I am making some mistakes during evaluation of integral which is messing up the answer. Please help.

Comment: Well, one way to check is to evaluate the surface integral directly and compare the result with what the divergence theorem gives you. The boundaries of your region are planes, so it should be easy to compute the surface integral.